# Why does the shell not terminate by kill -s TERM?

Tags: shell-script, process, kill

```
#!/bin/sh

trap 'trap - EXIT; echo exit' EXIT
trap 'echo term; exit' TERM

sleep 100
```

If I run `kill` for the PID of the shell process of the script, it does not terminate.
If I remove the TERM trap, and do the same, the shell will terminate. Why? Similarly, if I replace `sleep 100` by `sleep 100 & wait`, the shell will terminate by `kill`.

Answer (score -1):

The shell checks for outstanding traps only at specific checkpoints (at the end of a command) and when it is implicitly waiting for a running command, it is just before such a checkpoint.

On the other side: if you do not use `trap .... TERM`, the signal is used with default behavior which is to terminate the process (even the shell).

If you use `trap .... TERM`, you no longer have the default signal behavior for SIGTERM and this prevents the shell from being terminated.

Comment: I do not understand this: "and when it is implicitly waiting for a running command, it is just before such a checkpoint." What do you mean by _implicitly_ waiting? What is just before such a checkpoint?